# AWS Redshift Data type space allocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, types, amazon-redshift, block, space

I am planning to create id CHARACTER VARYING(100) ENCODE ZSTD, 
id2 CHARACTER VARYING(5000) ENCODE ZSTD.

Now my id and id1 are about size 20 characters only.

In AWS Redshift does the space allocation happen based on actual data size which is 20 or does it allocate first based on defined size which is 100 and 5000 respectively. If so how is the performance effected on these scenarios.

Thanks
TOM

Comment: You should reduce the size if you can as Redshift does have to expand these columns internally to full size. Keeping the varchar size small if possible should be better.

Comment: You mean the Redshift will allocate blocks at the initial phase or does it keep adding space as and when needed.

Comment: Really this is not a critical part of the work that needs to be done to make redshift as fast and efficient as possible, but i recommend not over-allocating the specified varchar size. If you know the maximum size, just use that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here.

Storage: With varchars, the amount of space consumed is based on the actual amount of space required, not the length (in bytes) declared.

Query Performance: Redshift does not know in advance how many bytes will be required to hold the varchar. It allocates the number of bytes based on the length declared for the varchar. It will cause queries to consume more memory which can in certain cases cause queries to spill to disk. This can have particularly negative impact on vacuum performance.

Summary: Declare varchars to be as short as possible. So, in your case if it's 20 or so, maybe 25-30 would be a good length to go with.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Redshift stores data using a [Compression Encoding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Compression_encodings.html), so it is not vital to allocate the minimum space.

It is often best to allow Redshift to choose the compression type when data is loaded via the `COPY` command, rather than specifying it yourself. This will result in the most efficient method being chosen, based on the first 100,000 rows loaded.